# Theming a webform file upload widget

Tags: theming, forms, webforms, files

I'm trying to replace the upload and remove buttons in a webform file upload widget with visual icons.

I'm having trouble for a number of reasons but the most confusing is this:

[image: file upload field widget screenshot]
[image: screenshot of the markup of the filefield widget]

I don't see where in the markup the "Browse..." and "no file selected" text is coming from? I've tried altering the `$variables['element']['upload_button']['value']` in `hook_preprocess_webform_element` and I didn't see any change in the value of the button or description.

If I remove `type="file"` and change the type to text, the "no file selected" note disappears too.

I have no idea what's going on.

For reference here's what I'm going for (left is after file upload, right is before file upload):

[image: screenshot of desired button appearance]

I'm using Drupal 7, Webform with Civicrm, and AutoUpload.

Comment: Its the browser that adds the button and "no file selected" text to all file uploads. **[How to rename HTML “browse” button of an input type=file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button-of-an-input-type-file)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely a Javascript / jQuery related questions rather then Drupal.

The button label and text is defined by the browser which you cannot tweak in Drupal. But with Javascript / jQuery, you can override and take over event for creating your own file upload button.

Since jQuery is included in Drupal, a jQuery library should be suitable for you. [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) is one of the best library for this purpose.

I found there are 2 contrib modules. They are [jQuery File Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_file_upload) and [jQuery Upload FAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqfuploadfapi).